# How do I stop NUnit TestCaseSource listing the same test several times?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, nunit

Consider the following code:

```
    private static object[] testStrings =
    {
        new object[] { "string1" },
        new object[] { "string2" },
        new object[] { "string3" },
        new object[] { "string4" }
    };

    [Test, TestCaseSource("testStrings")]
    public void CanParseString(string stringToTest)
    {
        //...
    }
```

This then ends up massively polluting the test results like in the following image. Now imagine when there are dozens of tests each with several sets of test data.

[image]

Is there a way of forcing NUnit/Visual Studio to only show just the test that was run and not each individual piece of test data that was passed to said test?

Or perhaps I've set the TestCaseSource up wrong in which case I'd appreciate knowing where I've gone wrong.

Comment: Each of those _is_ a different test, each with a different input. They can all fail independently of each other, and so are correctly shown as separate test runs.

Comment: Good point, I suppose I hadn't really thought of the list as a list of *runs*. I'd just been thinking of it as a list of unit tests.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can, and as @adrianbanks alludes to in the comments you probably shouldn't.

From the NUnit documentation on [Parameterized tests](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/wiki/Parameterized-Tests):

> Multiple sets of arguments cause the **creation of multiple tests**.

Because the `TestCaseSource` argument (and indeed `TestCase`) expose multiple tests to the test runner, you can't get Visual Studio to regroup these as a single test.